# cloud-init-output.log increases it size very quickly on RHEL 8

Tags: linux, rhel, cloud-init, rhel8

I use Linux machine on AWS EC2 instance with Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.6 and my cloud-init-output.log is increasing its size very quickly causing my app logs to stop writing in one-two days even though I have 20GB of storage.

```
user$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G  195M  1.7G  11% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda2       20G   17G  3.5G  83% /
tmpfs           373M     0  373M   0% /run/user/1000

user$ ls -ltr /var/log
total 10499168
drwxr-x---. 2 chrony chrony          6 Jun 15  2021 chrony
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root            6 Apr  5 18:43 qemu-ga
drwx------. 2 root   root            6 Apr  8 04:50 insights-client
drwx------. 2 root   root            6 May  3 08:58 private
-rw-rw----. 1 root   utmp            0 May  3 08:58 btmp
-rw-------. 1 root   root            0 May  3 08:59 maillog
-rw-------. 1 root   root            0 May  3 08:59 spooler
drwxr-x---. 2 sssd   sssd           73 Jun  3 11:15 sssd
drwx------. 2 root   root           23 Jul 12 14:43 audit
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root           23 Jul 12 14:44 tuned
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root       128263 Jul 12 14:44 cloud-init.log
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root           43 Jul 12 14:44 rhsm
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root          806 Jul 12 14:44 kdump.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root         1017 Jul 12 14:45 choose_repo.log
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root           67 Jul 12 14:47 amazon
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root         1560 Jul 14 05:04 hawkey.log
-rw-------. 1 root   root        26318 Jul 14 06:39 secure
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root   utmp         4224 Jul 14 06:58 wtmp
-rw-rw-r--. 1 root   utmp       292292 Jul 14 06:58 lastlog
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root        10752 Jul 14 07:00 dnf.rpm.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root        48816 Jul 14 07:00 dnf.librepo.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root   root        97219 Jul 14 07:00 dnf.log
-rw-------. 1 root   root        12402 Jul 14 07:01 cron
-rw-------. 1 root   root   2160833934 Jul 14 07:02 messages
-rw-r-----. 1 root   adm    5257112056 Jul 14 07:03 cloud-init-output.log
```

I changed logging level from default DEBUG to ERROR in /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d but it didn't help. Messages are also filling up fast.

Is this log file even supposed to be filling in after the EC2 instance is up?

Is there something I can do to stop the size increase?

I tried also to manually do the logrotate `logrotate --force /etc/logrotate.d/` but it didn't do much.

Comment: The log shouldn't fill that quickly. Is there a particular message being spammed to the log?

Comment: @falcojr It seems that I have a lot of application logs that are written in cloud-init-outout.log. I am starting the application from User data but that shouldn't be the reason for it to write the logs in the  cloud-init-outout.log. Do you have any idea why is that happening?

Comment: Logging configuration for cloud-init is overridable, so it's possible you have a logging configuration setup to do something you don't want. The default is defined in /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/05_logging.cfg, but could be sourced from a few different places. You could try filing a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init . If you attach the result of `cloud-init collect-logs` (with a `-u` if you don't have sensitive userdata), it makes it much easier to troubleshoot these sorts of issues.